# Why a single document.write statement is loading both jquery minified and the full jquery files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document.write, duplicates

I'm experiencing right now an interesting fact:

If I write this to load only jQuery minified version:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../rtvizion/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>');
```

both versions of jQuery files are being loaded:

```
jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

as can be seen in Google Chrome Sources:

[image]

If I comment out that `document.write` line then no jQuery file gets loaded.

The problem I have with both files loading is that it's creating duplicate objects/handlers in my own code.

Of course I can safely delete the one not minified (jquery-1.10.2.js) since I'm not using/referencing  it anywhere but I'm really curious about what's causing this behavior...

Why is this happening?

Comment: Use the element inspector to check how many script tags are added to DOM.

Comment: Is your `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` the original jQuery file? Maybe it's loading the other one for some strange reason?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes the original ones... I did not touch them.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible that  it's caused by that line. Are you 10000% sure the other file isn't getting included elsewhere in your document? Despite the fact that when you comment out that line, nothing gets loaded?

Comment: What happens if you just use a script tag instead of document.write('<...

Comment: Yep... but the thing is the `document.write`, isn't it?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: @chim I'm doing this inside another `.js` file to dynamically insert the scripts.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else but I can't help with just the picture and one line of code.

Comment: yeah need more info, it could be any of the other js

Comment: @SalmanA interesting ideed: I checked Chrome's `Elements` tab and only the minified jQuery is being inserted in the page source... so I guess this is a bug regarding Chrome's `Sources` tab. Not sure...

Comment: @j08691 WOOT! I found the problem after posting the question... I'll answer it afterwards...

Comment: missing single quote `'` here `.min.js"');` or is just a typo?

Comment: @RahilWazir that was just a typo while pasting the code in the question. :)

Comment: Do you have `jquery-1.10.2.js`, `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and a `jquery.min.map` in your Scripts folder? Can you check if `General > Source : Enable JS source maps` is enabled in the settings of the chrome dev tools, if yes please check the behavior is gone when you disable it.

Comment: @t.niese that's it bro! This fixed what looked like an "issue" to me. In fact this is a feature... I had thought about doing this before but didn't try. If you want, add this comment as an answer and I'll accept it! Do it... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery uses SourceMaps, this enables you debug minimized code.

When you open the console and the setting `General > Source : Enable JS source maps` is enabled, then chrome checks for the SourceMap, and out of the sourcemap <del>creates</del> maps to the original version.

This is why you see both version.

You see both files, because a minimized file could contain multiple files, which when source map is enabled will be displayed as individual ones.

**EDIT**
The files referenced by the source map are not immediately loaded so they don't appear in the network tab. Only if the content is displayed while debugging they will be loaded and only at that time you will see them in the network tab.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi i also had the same problem a while ago, it gave me headache :D But there I had a bunch of files appearing in sources but not in the networking tab, that was really frustrating.

Comment: and you see from my answer that my problem is down the pipe... this really got me confused! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... after posting the question and following the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117341/why-a-single-document-write-statement-is-loading-both-jquery-minified-and-the-fu#comment31773523_21117341) from Salman A. I could see that the problem was not with `document.write` but with another app that loads dynamic widgets into the page. The widget also has a script tag linking to jQuery. This causes the problem in my case.

<s>Google Chrome's `Sources` tab is showing both jQuery files but if I look at the [page's source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117341/why-a-single-document-write-statement-is-loading-both-jquery-minified-and-the-fu#comment31773888_21117341) in the `Elements` tab I see only the minified one present. Looks like the `Sources` view is misleading!</s>

t.niese's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118446/114029) it all.